# Show that Lu is m-reducible to the language L = {⟨M, x⟩ | M(x) terminates with an empty tape}

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability, decidability

Question: Given a language L, L = {⟨M, x⟩ | M(x) terminates with an empty tape}, show that Lu is m-reducible to L by finding a computable function f: Σ* -> Σ*, where for every w, w ∈ Lu if and only if f(w) ∈ L.
(Recall Lu = {⟨M, x⟩ | x ∈ L(M)})

My general understanding of m-reducibility is that if you can assume there exists a decider machine M' for M, and given this assumption prove that there is a decider for Lu, you can arrive at a contradiction and therefore prove L is undecidable.

This problem is asking to demonstrate it using a function though. How does one do this?

Comment: A (many-one) reduction from $A$ to $B$ **is** a function $f : A \to B$ such that $f(x) \in A \iff f(x) \in B$, and $f$ is computable. What you are describing is just a consequence of the existence of such a reduction. I.e., if  $A \le_m B$ and there is a decider for $B$ then there is a decider for $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that there are when running $M(x)$, there are three possibles results:

- $M(x)$ terminates in an accepting state;
- $M(x)$ terminates in a rejecting state;
- $M(x)$ doesn't terminate.

The reduction you want is such that $x\in L(M) \Leftrightarrow M'(x')$ terminates with an empty tape, $\langle M', x'\rangle$ being equal to $f(\langle M, x\rangle)$.

What you could do is tweak $M$ a little bit such that:

- if $M$ accepts $x$, then it empties the tape before terminating;
- if $M$ rejects $x$, then it write a symbol on the tape before terminating.